# excel vba: hide text file?

Tags: vba, excel, hide

I am trying to use the following vba code to hide a text file but for some reason I am getting a user type defined error on this line

```
Dim fso As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.FileSystemObject
```

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

```
Dim fso As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.FileSystemObject
Dim oFile As IWshRuntimeLibrary.file
Set oFile = fso.GetFile("S:\Tasks\Tenders\" & Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\log.txt")
oFile.Attributes = oFile.Attributes Or Hidden Or System
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add a reference (*Tools -> References*) to *Windows Script Host Object Model* for that *specific* interface.

Better to add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* and:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim oFile As Scripting.File
Set oFile = fso.GetFile("???")

oFile.Attributes = oFile.Attributes Or Hidden Or System
```

Or even better, just use the built-in [`SetAttr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266286(v=vs.60).aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a reference to `Windows Scripting Host` from Tools-References to use the code as written.

Alternatively, you could use late binding. To do it with late binding you would replace the line that is causing you problems with these two lines:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```